# Conclusion from nonsingularity of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A\in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ is nonsingular, then:
a. $P_A(0)\neq 0$, where $P_A$ is characteristic polynomial matrix $A$
b. $\ker(AA^T)=\{0\}$
c. matrix $I_n-A$ is also nonsingular.

a. is not true.  $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
  \end{array} \right)$ is nonsingular and $P_A(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^2$
b. it is true:
$AA^Tx=0\Leftrightarrow A^Tx=0 \Leftrightarrow x =0$.  Here, I use the fact that $\det A=\det A^T$ so both matrixes are reverable.
c. it is not true, $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
  \end{array} \right)$, then $I_n-A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1  \\
  \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0  \\ 
0 & 0  \\
  \end{array} \right)$  is not nonsingular.

Am I right ?

Comment: Your counter-example to a. is not right, since $P_A(0)=1$ in your case.

Comment: Ok, I will try to repair it. What about b. and c. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. is true, since $P_A(0)=\det(A-0I)=\det(A)\neq 0$, because $A$ is nonsingular.

b. and c. are ok.

Comment: Is it ok to say that nonsingular matrix has no $0$ on principial diagonal ?

Comment: @HaskellFun No. For example $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ is nonsingular and *only* has zeroes in the principal diagonal.